# How can I make the button pause remember where the MediaPlayer stopped?

Tags: java, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I made a MediaPlayer some time ago and I faced a big issue. The audio can't be played in the background so I must use Service. At this point, I managed to play the music and to stop it, but when I click play again, it restarts and I don't know what to do. I am new to coding. Other than that I want to make a working seekbar and a textView for player position, but that for another time. If there is someone to help me I would really appreciate it.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
btPause = findViewById(R.id.btPauseMusic);
btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlayMusic);

btPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {

    startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class));

    btPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});

btPause.setOnClickListener(v -> {

    stopService(new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class));

    btPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});

}
```

The service:

```
public class BackgroundMusicService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ding_dong);
mediaPlayer.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

mediaPlayer.stop();
}
}
```

Comment: add the code where you are stopping and playing again.

Comment: Is the first one I added. The btPlay and Pause where I set OnClickListener. There is nothing else. Maybe you refer to something else.

Comment: In both button you are starting and stopping the service, that why music play from the start. Its like you are resetting the music.

Comment: And what should I do?

Comment: start the with notification and add two buttons on that notification on to pause the music and one to start.

Comment: do you want me to provide the code for this solution?

Comment: I think it would be better, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this notification code in your `BackgroundMusicService` inside on `onCreate`.

```
Intent stopSelf = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class);
        stopSelf.setAction("Stop");
        PendingIntent pStopSelf = PendingIntent
                .getService(this, 0, stopSelf
                        , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification notification;
        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                        0, "Pause", pStopSelf
                ).build();
Intent startSelf = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class);
    stopSelf.setAction("Start");
    PendingIntent pstartSelf = PendingIntent
            .getService(this, 0, stopSelf
                    , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Notification notifications;
    NotificationCompat.Action actions =
            new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                    0, "Play", pstartSelf
            ).build();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel("channal", "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channal")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentText("Music.")
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .addAction(action)
                    .addAction(actions).build();
        } else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channal")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("App name")
                    .setContentText("Music.")
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .addAction(action)
                     .addAction(actions)
                    .build();
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        startForeground(1, notification);
```

In `onStartCommand` your intent actions are called where you can pause and play the music by using the `length`.

```
 int length=0;
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if ("STOP".equals(intent.getAction())) {
          //inside here pause  the music.
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }else if ("Start".equals(intent.getAction())) {
      //inside here play the music with seekto by length where the music was.
             mediaPlayer.start();
             mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
       
        }
       
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

**Note**: If you still did not understand anything you can ask me in the comment.

Comment: I did as suggested, but now I got a bunch of errors: 1.  the symbol setAction cannot be resolved. 2. Unknown class: 'Build.VERSION.SDK_INT'. 3. Cannot resolve symbol 'length' and many others.

Comment: I am going to document myself better and try to do it on my own. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: for Cannot resolve symbol 'length' just delcare the variable as int

Comment: these are not errors just import the required libraries.